# Django is giving me NoReverseMatch at /post/5/ error when I deploy while everything works fine locally

Tags: python, django

Django is giving me NoReverseMatch error for no reason. Everything works fine in my local environment but as soon as I deploy, I get this error. I got this error yesterday also, when I implemented a button for adding posts. At that time, I tried to find the error but couldn't and gave up but today when I opened the page, the error was gone. Now I feel that whenever I implement a new feature, django likes to throw that error at me for no reason and later it gets fixed on its own?? This is driving me crazy please I would really appreciate if someone can help. Also, this is my first post here so try to forgive me if I make a mistake in posting.

Error:
NoReverseMatch at /post/5/

Reverse for 'post_delete' not found. 'post_delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.postList, name='post_list'),
    path('post/new/', views.postNew, name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.postDetail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/edit/<int:pk>/', views.postEdit, name='post_edit'),
    path('post/delete/<int:pk>/', views.postDelete, name='post_delete'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import Post
from blog.forms import PostForm
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

# Create your views here.


def postList(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by(
        "published_date").reverse()
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, "blog/post_list.html", context)


def postDetail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    context = {
        'post': post
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)


def postNew(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect("post_detail", pk=post.pk)
        else:
            return redirect("post_new")
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', context)


def postEdit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect("post_detail", pk=post.pk)
        else:
            return redirect("post_edit", pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', context)

def postDelete(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect("post_list")
```

The template which is giving error

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<article class="post">
    <time style="float: right; margin-right: 20px; opacity: 0.7;">published : {{post.published_date}}</time>
    <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}" style="text-decoration: none; float: left;">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
    
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <aside style="float: left;">
        <a class="btn btn secondary" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}">
            {% include './icons/pencil-fill.svg' %}
        </a>
    </aside>
    <aside style="float: left;">
        <a class="btn btn secondary" href="{% url 'post_delete' pk=post.pk %}">
            {% include './icons/lock-fill.svg' %}
        </a>
    </aside>
    {% endif %}
    
    <p style="clear: both; word-wrap: break-word;" >{{post.text}}</p>
</article>

{% endblock content %}
```

Base Template which is extended

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Ayush's Blog
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/blog.css' %}>
</head>

<body style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <header class="page-header">
        <div class="container">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu">
                    {% include './icons/file-earmark-plus.svg' %}
                </a>
            {% endif %}
            <h1><a href="/" style="text-decoration: none;">Ayush's Blog</a></h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for any and all help

Edit:

Here is the full error message

```
NoReverseMatch at /post/5/
Reverse for 'post_delete' not found. 'post_delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://rail.pythonanywhere.com/post/5/
Django Version: 3.2.15
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post_delete' not found. 'post_delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 698, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/rail/rail.pythonanywhere.com',
 '/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 08 Sep 2022 20:28:45 +0530
Error during template rendering
In template /home/rail/rail.pythonanywhere.com/blog/templates/blog/base.html, error at line 19

Reverse for 'post_delete' not found. 'post_delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
9       </title>
10      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
11          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
12      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
13      <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/blog.css' %}>
14  </head>
15  
16  <body style="overflow-y: scroll;">
17      <header class="page-header">
18          <div class="container">
19              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
20                  <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu">
21                      {% include './icons/file-earmark-plus.svg' %}
22                  </a>
23              {% endif %}
24              <h1><a href="/" style="text-decoration: none;">Ayush's Blog</a></h1>
25          </div>
26      </header>
27      {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
28  
29  </body>
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/rail.pythonanywhere.com/blog/views.py, line 24, in postDetail
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py, line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py, line 61, in render
            return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 170, in render
                    return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 150, in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 62, in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 315, in render
                return nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 449, in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py, line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rail/.virtualenvs/rail.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 698, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg) …
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
Ayush

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'Y1p4H9F550Daj5nMZzMnmAb7p9kObWGvojJtkx9OvWyVDBwKgU8wCs4895iLStvA'
sessionid   
'c52iun8qj0bdubtnxe65jncte6ke2m3n'
META
Variable    Value
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
''
CSRF_COOKIE 
'Y1p4H9F550Daj5nMZzMnmAb7p9kObWGvojJtkx9OvWyVDBwKgU8wCs4895iLStvA'
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/usr/local/openresty/nginx/html'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.9'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'close'
HTTP_COOKIE 
('csrftoken=Y1p4H9F550Daj5nMZzMnmAb7p9kObWGvojJtkx9OvWyVDBwKgU8wCs4895iLStvA; '
 'sessionid=c52iun8qj0bdubtnxe65jncte6ke2m3n')
HTTP_HOST   
'rail.pythonanywhere.com'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://rail.pythonanywhere.com/'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
 'Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27')
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    
'103.27.8.109'
HTTP_X_REAL_IP  
'103.27.8.109'
PATH_INFO   
'/post/5/'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'10.0.0.75'
REMOTE_PORT 
'44688'
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
REQUEST_URI 
'/post/5/'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SERVER_NAME 
'rail.pythonanywhere.com'
SERVER_PORT 
'80'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
uwsgi.node  
b'blue-liveweb17'
uwsgi.version   
b'2.0.19.1'
wsgi.errors 
<uwsgi_file__bin_user_wsgi_wrapper.ErrorLogFile object at 0x7f8002d56d60>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
<built-in function uwsgi_sendfile>
wsgi.input  
<uwsgi._Input object at 0x7f8002976070>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
False
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module mysite.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com']
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
PosixPath('/home/rail/rail.pythonanywhere.com')
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': PosixPath('/home/rail/rail.pythonanywhere.com/db.sqlite3'),
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD  
'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER  
'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM   
'sha256'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
FORM_RENDERER   
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ar-dz', 'Algerian Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('ig', 'Igbo'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('ky', 'Kyrgyz'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('tg', 'Tajik'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tk', 'Turkmen'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('uz', 'Uzbek'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'ar-dz', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
MEDIA_URL   
'/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT  
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'mysite.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY  
'same-origin'
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'mysite.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
[PosixPath('/home/rail/rail.pythonanywhere.com/static')]
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
None
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': [],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'mysite.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
```

Here is the urls.py of the project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: When does django throw this error. is it when you perform an action? if yes what action are you performing.

Comment: Please show us the full traceback

Comment: Check again your project `urls.py`.

Comment: @Martins It happens whenever I create a new url in urls.py of my app and link it with a new fuction in views.py and then call it using url tag of django

Comment: @NKSM I have checked it but can't spot any error. Also I have also posted the urls.py of the project in an edit, too.

Comment: This error seems to come from template, can you show your detail html page where you have the delete functionality.

Comment: @Martins I have included it under the heading "Template which is giving error". It has the delete functionality.

Comment: If it's happening every time you add a url, then you are probably not reloading your web app after making the change